Tracing in LMAX disrupter processing
I am looking for options to be able to fetch and track logs in the flow of handlers processing in LMAX ring buffer, i.e, for an particular message posted into ring buffer, get all its respective logs which are generated from its processing in the disrupter flow.
I'm trying to understand if there is a good way to handle tracing and logging which can also integrate with opentelemetry so that tracing information is passed on to external calls if any.
The option I currently have is, when a message is pushed, generate MDC context and add that into the event. In each of the handler, at the beginning get the context and add it into current thread MDC context so that logs will have that info. But the catch is that I have open telemetry integrated for the other flows, and for any outgoing transactions, the trace information of that transaction will not be carried to those external calls.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
